# removes leading zeroes, but leaves one necessary From String in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

Given:

```
a = 00099999325
b = 1254
```

How do I remove leading zeros  but leaves one necessary

This is the output I'm expecting:

```
099999325
1254
```

Currently,  am using this function but i need to optimize it :

```
//removes leading zeroes, but leaves one if necessary
public static String removeLeadingZeroes(String s) {

    return s.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");

}
```

can anyone help me please ? thank you for advanced

Comment: What do you need to optimize it for? CPU cycles? Memory usage? Readability?

Comment: Why not just add a zero after running your regex: s = "0" + s;

Comment: @Kayaman my function remove all leading zero , but i want to keep  at least one zero

Comment: @kamkam - You didn't answer the question.  Kayaman asked **why** you want to do this.  (You may have some misconceptions about what this will achieve ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex [`^0*(0\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/Q12y8B/1) like this:

```
return s.replaceFirst("^0*(0\\d+)", "$1");
```

**I/O**

```
000099999325 -> 099999325
1254         -> 1254
1230004      -> 1230004
```

Comment: i edited my post 
given 
`a = 00099999325
b = 1254
output 
099999325
1254`

Comment: @kamkam my regex work in both cases, check [this](https://regex101.com/r/7HLNEH/1)

Comment: @YCF_L please correct your answer. This regex yields wrong result for any number that ends with or has multiple zeros within. Eg. 1230004 -> 12304

Comment: @Kharel you are correct, I fix it, thank you for the helpful comment :)